# A General Method To Transpile A Code in Eclipse CLP to CHR

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp, constraint-handling-rules

My question is a little general but the answer to my specific question could be very helpful. The general question is "Is there any general method to transfer code in Eclipse CLP prolog to a Constraint Handling Rules (CHR) code?". I know that the CHR code will be compiled to a prolog code anyhow.

The specific question is "is there any algorithm or any formal rules to transfer [this example code](https://eclipseclp.org/examples/queens_simple.ecl.txt) for N-Queens in Eclipse CLP to CHR code?".